# Navigation drawer for multiple activities not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-menu

I'm trying to get the same navigation drawer for multiple activities. At the moment I have a BaseActivity that holds the navigation drawer and a MainActivity that extends the BaseActivity class. It works fine when i run the BaseActivity first but instead if i run MainActivity first (Which is what I want to do) the navigation drawer doesn't work when i swipe the screen from left to right. I've been stuck on this for while now and can't seem to figure out what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

**HomeActivity Class**

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


    }
}
```

**BaseActivity Class**

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String[] menuList;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private CharSequence drawerTitle;
    private CharSequence title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

        // Initialize drawer's list of items. Get the array for the list
        menuList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuItems);

        // Get the drawers layout
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // Get the list view
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview listView
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                menuList));

        // Set listener for the list item clicks
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**activity_base.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: why are you doing that? Use NavigationDrawer only in one Activity and use fragments for rest of the things. Have a look at the demo example they have provided.

Comment: Im learning as im going, so I thought thats how it was supposed to be implemented. But using fragments just cleared everything up! thanks